# Use of || in a bash pipeline

Tags: bash

I have a directory with zero or more files with names like

```
on_common_20131020.xml
on_common_20131021.xml
on_common_20131022.xml
```

and so on.  In order to extract the datestamp of the most recent one, I know I can use the following hack

```
ls -rt on_common* | tail -n 1 | egrep -o '[0-9]{8}'
```

(though if there is a better way I'd love to know).  Now the thing is, I want to capture this value in a script, so I have the following line:

```
RECENT=$(ls -rt on_common* | tail -n 1 | egrep -o '[0-9]{8}')
```

However, there may not be *any* such files in the directory, in which case `ls` will fail, and I want the value of RECENT to be, in that case, 00010101.  I know how to use ' c1 || c2' to execute command c2 if and only if command c1 fails, but was unable to find anything that would give me the equivalent of this pseudo-Bash:

```
RECENT=$(ls -rt on_common* | tail -n 1 | egrep -o '[0-9]{8}') || '00010101'  # WRONG
```

Yes I can do this with `if`...`fi`, but is there a single expression form?

**EDIT**

It turns out there was just a missing echo.  The Bash syntax says:

> A list is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one of the operators ‘;’, ‘&’, ‘&&’, or ‘||’, and optionally terminated by one of ‘;’, ‘&’, or a newline.

So I was close in that pipelines can be separated by `||` but the expression to the right of the `||` was not a pipeline (it wasn't even a command).

And another pedantic note for anyone that ends up here.  Using `-t` in `ls` when there is a datestamp in the filename is pretty dangerous; someone could touch a filename with a datesamp in it.  I ended up with:

```
RECENT=$(ls -1 on_common* 2>/dev/null | sort -r | egrep -om1 '[0-9]{8}' || echo '00010101')
```

which is a combination of Blue Moon's (redirect to dev/null) and jaap's answer (lack on inner parentheses and -m for egrep).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about bash and would be a better fit at [unix.se].

Comment: Oh good point, feel free to move it over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    RECENT=$((ls -rt on_common* 2>/dev/null| tail -n 1 | egrep -o '[0-9]{8}') 
|| echo '0001-01-01')
```

will do the equivalent of `c1 || c2` as you desired.

Note that I redirected stderr to /dev/null ( `2>/dev/null`) in case `ls` fails. If *do* you want to see the error, you can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

First, your search expression can be a bit shorter

```
ls -t on_common* | egrep -om1 '[0-9]{8}'
```

For the second part, this should work

```
RECENT=$(ls -t on_common* | egrep -om1 '[0-9]{8}' || echo "0001-01-01")
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about grep's `-m`.  Very nice!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sub-shell like this :

```
command1 |(command2 || <treatment if command2 fails>)
var=$(command1 |(command2 || <treatment if command2 fails>)) # to get the commands suite output in a variable
```

And if you want execute treatment only if command1 fails :

```
(command1 || <treatment if command1 fails>)|command2
var=$((command1 || <treatment if command1 fails>)|command2) # to get the commands suite output in a variable
```